# Simple_html_dom load_file function not working

Tags: php

I am going bald of this error!  I have code that work and code that doesn't work.  Don't know what the issue is.

The error message is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object

look towards the bottom of my my non-working code.

The lines of code in question are:

```
$post_link = $item->get_link();
$htmlDOM->load_file($post_link);
$image = $htmlDOM->find('img', 0);
if ($image->src) {
   echo '<media:thumbnail url="' . $image->src . '" width="320" />';
}
```

Working code:

```
    <?php
// Create DOM from URL or file
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
include_once('functions.inc');

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://themaroontiger.com/an-advantageous-affair/');
$image = $html->find('img', 0);
if ($image->src) {
   echo '<media:thumbnail url="' . $image->src . '" width="320" />';
}
exit;
?>
```

None Working Code:

```
    <?php
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . "\n";
?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
<channel>
<title>Maroon Tiger Feed</title>
<link>http://www.webmaster-source.com</link>
<description>
Maroon Tiger Feed
</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<?
include_once('simple_html_dom2.php');
include_once('simplepie.inc');
include_once('functions.inc');

// MAIN BEGIN
$feed = new SimplePie(); // Create a new instance of SimplePie

$htmlDOM = new simple_html_dom();
$feed->set_feed_url(array(
        'http://themaroontiger.com/feed/'
));

$feed->enable_cache('false'); //Do we cache
$feed->set_cache_duration(600); //The cache duration

//$feed->enable_xml_dump(isset($_GET['xmldump']) ? true : false);

$success = $feed->init(); // Initialize SimplePie

$feed->handle_content_type(); // Take care of the character encoding
?>

<? if ($success): ?>
<? $itemlimit=0; ?>

<? foreach($feed->get_items() as $item): ?>
<? if ($itemlimit==20) { break; } ?>
<item>
<title><?= decode_entities($item->get_title()); ?> </title>
<link><?= $item->get_permalink(); ?></link>
<dc:creator>
<?
if ($author = $item->get_author())
        {
                echo $author->get_name();
        }
?>
</dc:creator>
<category><? if ($the_category = $item->get_category()) {
                echo $the_category->get_label();
             } else {
                echo 'Facebook Feed';
             };?>
</category>
<description><![CDATA[
<? echo $item->get_description(); ?>
]]></description>
<guid isPermaLink="false"><? echo $item->get_id(); ?></guid>
<pubDate><? echo $item->get_date('D, d M Y H:i:s T'); ?></pubDate>
<?
$post_link = $item->get_link();
$htmlDOM->load_file($post_link);
$image = $htmlDOM->find('img', 0);
if ($image->src) {
   echo '<media:thumbnail url="' . $image->src . '" width="320" />';
}
?>
</item>
<? $itemlimit++ ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
<? endif; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looping through a feed, maybe some of the links you are trying to read from aren't valid and since you try to read from them without any checking, that's why you might be getting the error message. So after $htmlDOM->load_file($post_link); check if the file was loaded before continuing.